# Flutter - How to overflow horizontal listview?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-listview

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f36dda5165fa3080fa38533484890e73)

I'm building a website using Flutter Web. I have a horizontal `ListView` that shows items. I have a `ConstrainedBox` that sets the `maxWidth` to 1200. This cuts the `ListView` on both sides.

When I add the `OverflowBox`, `ListView` starts at the beginning of the page. How can I overflow it correctly that `ListView` begins where it should be and the rest of the items won't cut, so the user can scroll and see the items outside of the `ConstrainedBox`?

[image]

***with overflow:***
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to represent the items,  and it won't cut off initially ?

Comment: Basically, I need image #1 as the beginning spot and overflow to right or left as the user scrolls. The issue is that I couldn't make it begin from that spot so I have behavior like image #2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `ping (pixeltoast)` from the Flutter discord server, it's answered [here](https://discord.com/channels/608014603317936148/608016344520196173/980173867119173692).

```dart
   return SizedBox(
      height: 663,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return ScrollConfiguration(
            behavior: _MyCustomScrollBehavior(),
            child: ListView.separated(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: max(0.0, (constraints.maxWidth - 800) / 3)),
              controller: _controller,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: items.length,
              separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(width: 16),
              itemBuilder: (_, i) => items[i],
            ),
          );
        }
      ),
    );
```